# Can't read data from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[Here it is Firestore Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71yVj.png)

I am trying to register user with phone number, My aim is user can only register with only one phone number means there is no repetition , SO while registring i am reading in firestore that if entered number is available in database than it shows error else it will register. But while reading the data firestore return nothing. Also it not showing any error toast.The same function is working fine in other app.

**Here is the code**

```
 mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    mFireStore.collection("USERS")
        .whereEqualTo("Number", number.text.toString())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {

                if( document != null ){

                    Log.i("Null","Document Not null")

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Phone Number Already Exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }else{

                    val OTP = Intent(this@MainActivity,OTPActivity::class.java)
                    OTP.putExtra("Name",NAME.text.toString())
                    OTP.putExtra("Number","+"+92+number.text.toString())
                    OTP.putExtra("Age",age.text.toString())
                    OTP.putExtra("District",district.text.toString())
                    startActivity(OTP)
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(this,exception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

**Here are my security Rules**

```
match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if true;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `number.text.toString()`?

Comment: The value of number is the "Number" stored in database i,e 03162026593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment:

> The value of number is the "Number" stored in database i,e 03162026593

So when you are using the follow call:

```
.whereEqualTo("Number", number.text.toString())
```

You are actually passing `03162026593` and **not** `+9203162026593` as it is in your database. To solve this, you should use the following query instead:

```
mFireStore.collection("USERS")
    .whereEqualTo("Number", "+92" + number)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */);
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday but it's not working then. Also without "+92" i have another project with the same code it's working perfectly fine.But now when i try again "+92" it worked. Don't know what the heck is this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query Firestore database, you need to create index first. Go through [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) and it would serve your purpose, hopefully!

Comment: But , I did'nt create index before this is the first time  the problem happended. Everytime i tried it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When querying `.whereEqualTo("Number", number.text.toString())`, shouldn't you also add +92 to the number, like `.whereEqualTo("Number", "+"+92+number.text.toString())`?